# How to turn off SecureConversationToken in WCF web service

Tags: java, wcf, web-services, wss4j

I have a WCF web service with WS-* security and I need to write a Java client for it using WSS4J API.
But, as it turns out WSS4J does not support the `<SecurityContextToken>` and `<DerivedKeyToken>` tags, which are specific to WS-SecureConversation.

is there a way to turn it off via code or better, via web.config?

**UPDATE:**

Service definition:

```
      <service name="my.service" 
           behaviorConfiguration="SecureTransport">
    <endpoint 
      address="mex" 
      binding="mexHttpBinding" 
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <endpoint 
      contract="my.interface" 
      binding="wsHttpBinding" 
      bindingConfiguration="UsernameAndPassword"/>
  </service>
```

Behaviour and Bindings:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SecureTransport">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication   userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                                  customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="example.API.Security.CustomUserNameValidator, APISecurity" />
        <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=Example" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="UsernameAndPassword">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />            
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: What is your current WCF config (binding)?

Comment: I've updated the post with the wcf configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turn security context and probably also negotiation in your binding configuration:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="UsernameAndPassword">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="false"
                 negotiateServiceCredential="false" />            
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and if it works I'll come back here and mark your answer :)