# How To Change The Binding of a WCF Service

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I have a very simple (see any getting started sample online) wcf service library. And i can run it via the WCF Test Client exe on localhost.  But when accessing it via another client tool, like soapUI, i get errors. I believe the errors are related to security configuration of the service.

How can i change the binding of a service, like is suggested in this post:

["Invalid or expired security context token" when running after a debugging restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575799/invalid-or-expired-security-context-token-when-running-after-a-debugging-resta)

Is this in app.config or web.config.  my project doesnt even have a web.config.

Here's my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="NorthwindServices.ProductService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/NorthwindServices/ProductService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address ="" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                            contract="NorthwindServices.IProducts">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"
                    contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Are you running the service on a different machine to soapUI?

Comment: both are on localhost.